# Bind external svg to data

Tags: svg, d3.js

Community,

I would like to bind an external svg file to my data-array.

I loaded the element into my dom like this:

```
                defs = d3.select("defs");
                d3.html("combisymbol.svg", function(data) {
                //get a selection of the image so we can pull out the icon
                xml = d3.select(data); 
                icon = document.importNode(xml.select("#star").node(), true);
                icon.id = "staricon";

                defs.node().appendChild(icon);
               // console.log("icon", icon);
```

Then I tried to make it visible. I used the same approach as when I take circles that I bind to my data. With the circles it works, but my external svg is not visible.

```
            d3.select("body").select("div#divCombiSVG")
                    .selectAll("star")
                    .data(combiData)
                    .enter()
                    .append("svg:use")
                    .attr("xlink:href", "#staricon");
```

I don't see the svgs.

I have also tried this:

```
d3.select("body").select("div#divCombiSVG")
                    .selectAll("star")
                    .data(combiData)
                    .enter()
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width",200)
                    .attr("height",200)
                    .node().appendChild(icon);
```

But then the icon gets only added to the first data-element and not the second. Even though it's added to the first, it's still not visible.

The svg file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904          /DTD/svg10.dtd">
 <svg version="1.0" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 37.207 100" enable-background="new 0 0 37.207 100"
 xml:space="preserve">

<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="star" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" r2="43" 
orient='point'     points='3' radial-shift='0' outerCurve='86' 
outerOffset='4.1' innerCurve='56' innerOffset='2.2' d="M300,168 
C347.7790400396858,178.49361334198113 
345.7070270919484,217.64466544113793 337.23909236273084,228.5 
C350.87405522189334,226.59422068634012 385.8158673985199,244.3753308862077 371.014083110324,291
C338.0368273588341,327.1310557718112 
305.1670281299449,305.76111387252195 300,293 C294.83297187005513,305.76111387252195    
261.9631726411659,327.1310557718112 228.98591688967605,291 C214.1841326014801,244.37533088620776
249.12594477810666,226.59422068634015 262.7609076372691,228.50000000000003 
C254.29297290805158,217.64466544113793 252.22095996031422,178.4936133419811 300,168 " 
fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></path>

</svg>
```

combiData currently has two objects.
I have looked for hours at other examples but I can't make it work. I think I'm close though...I'm pretty new to d3 (but very motivated) so please be patient with me. :-)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: That svg is broken, so that might be the first problem. It's drawing the path outside of the viewport. plus it's not a star, if that matters.

Comment: also you're going to want to set the x and y attributes for the use element.

Comment: That is strange. I can see it perfectly well with <use xlink:href="#star" transform="translate(200,200)scale(.5,.5)"></use> (star was the former id)

Comment: Maybe something happened when I copied the svg content above (returns etc.)?

Comment: Yes, you're right about the x and y (in this case, cx and cy, isn't it?). Which version should I rather use? The one with xlink:href or the one with appendChild?

Comment: I have no idea. But your svg is broken and without more info I'm just guessing.  http://jsfiddle.net/0ch563s2/

Comment: It doesn't matter what svg file I use, nothing appears. I don't understand what I'm supposed to see on the jsfiddle page. Even an svg file with a simple circle doesn't show.

Comment: Thank you! I got it working with the simple circle file. Now I'll produce a new svg that hopefully works, too.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are doing a `.selectAll('star')` (searching for the tag `star`), which probably should have been a `.selectAll('#star')` (searching for a tag with id `star`).

Your second approach can be tweaked a little to work as well. Calling `node()` on a d3 selection always returns *just one node*. Hence, the subsequent `.appendChild` happens only on the first node.

You can try this, if you find this more amenable to what you wanted to do:

```
d3.select("body").select("div#divCombiSVG")
                .selectAll("star")
                .data(combiData)
                .enter()
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width",200)
                .attr("height",200)
                .each(function (d) {
                    this.appendChild(icon);
                });
```

---

Since in the comments you asked for which option to prefer: I would recommend the first approach of using the `use` element. It results in less code and you can even [refer to the file containing the star externally](http://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/) which means that you will not have to download and inline the SVG yourself (note the caveat about IE).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I thought that the selectAll command just reserves the space for the coming elements but that it doesn't select any "real" elements. That's why I just named them star which leads me to the question if the name that I give this empty selection is arbitrary?

Comment: `d3.selectAll` accepts a CSS3 selector and allows an eventual data-join with an array via the `.data` method. After the join, there are three kinds of elements in the selection: 1. elements which need to be created for new data elements (the `enter` set), 2. elements which have had their data updated (the `update` set) and 3. elements which need to be removed because the data corresponding them has disappeared (the `exit` set). Hence, `selectAll` does reserve space, but that is only part of what it does and the selection is not _named_, though it is usually given descriptive class name.